# Python doesn't enter while loop when I try using a string and a list of strings as an argument

Tags: python, string, list, loops

So what I'm trying to achieve is as follows.
We have a list of string values, this contains a transcript of a dialogue. The first string is a name of the sender. The second string is the message. Then the second message is either sent by the same person or is an answer by the recipient. There is no limit on how many messages can be sent by one individual in a row.
I want to collect the messages sent by one person in a row into one string, then the reply by the other person, if there are multiple messages then again, collected into a single string. I want to omit the names. 
So basically I want to end up with a transcript of the dialogue where person A sends a message then person B sends an answer and so on.

The code I have written is:

```
t = ["Kim","dialogue_k1_","Kim","dialogue_k2_","Tim","dialogue_t1_","Kim","dialogue_k3_","Tim", "dialogue_t2_", "Tim", "dialogue_t3_", "Tim", "dialogue_t4_"]
f = []

c = t[0]
i = 0
j = 0
l = 1

while i < len(t):

    while c != t[j]:
        j = j+2

    c = t[j]
    print("j is :", j)

    if (j-1) == l:
        f.append(t[i+1])
        l = l+2
        i = j
    else:
        ss = ""
        print(l, j)
        while l < (j-1):
            ss  = ss + t[l]
            l = l+2
        f.append(ss)
        i = j

print(f)
```

What I would ideally get is something like ["dialogue_k1_dialogue_k2_","dialogue_t1_","dialogue_k3_","dialogue_t2_dialogue_t3_dialogue_t4_"]

What I get is an infinite loop.
In fact the code never seems to enter the second while loop for some reason.

I am new to python, I'm sure it's something trivial like indentation or not using the correct type of data or something, but I can't for the love of god find the reason why I never enter that second while loop.

It should enter because Kim is Kim then increment j by 2 twice so it jumps to Tim but it never does that.
In fact it never increments j so it never increments i either so infinite loop.
I'm pretty sure I'll feel like an idiot after someone helps me find the error at hand haha.

Comment: Your condition for second loop is not satisfying. `c==t[0]` is true

Comment: ahhhhh, oh god I really do feel like an idiot :)

Comment: although it only made me realise there are more fundamental flaws in this code

Answer (score 0):

I have come up with something. Have a look

```
f = []
for i in t:
    if t.index(i)%2==1:
        f.append(i)
print(f)
```

Since all the dialogues are at odd positions in the list of dialogues, I am just appending the elements at odd places inside the list f.

Output -

```
['dialogue_k1_', 'dialogue_k2_', 'dialogue_t1_', 'dialogue_k3_', 'dialogue_t2_', 'dialogue_t3_', 'dialogue_t4_']
```

Hope this was useful!!

Comment: Well, it's not exactly useful, the point is kind of to stitch together the dialogues from the same person into one string, I might have been not so clear on that one. But I got it to work in the meantime. Thanks for the effort anyways :D